# i want to clear all textbox in some group box in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a Windows form that have some GroupBox, i want to set all textbox.text in Groupboxes to 0. i wrote this code but not working.

```
foreach (var TTX in this.Controls)
{
    if (TTX is TextBox)
        ((TextBox) TTX).Text = (0).ToString(format: "c0");
}
```

Comment: Why you don't simplify the code writing `TTX.Text = "0";`?

Comment: Because c0 format adds the currency symbol from the current culture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct approach as your code above cannot work if the controls to handle are inside another control container. And GroupBox is a control container. So you need to enumerate all the groupbox and the controls inside that groupboxes.
However you can simplify a lot your code if you use the [OfType enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-6.0) to extract, first all groupboxes from the controls collection of the form, then, foreach groupbox use the same technique to extract just the textboxes contained in the controls collection of the current GroupBox. The advantage is clear if you see how the code doesn't need anymore complicated checks and casts to use a TextBox or GroupBox strong typed variable.

```
foreach (var grpBox in this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>())
{
     foreach(var TTX in grpBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
         TTX.Text = 0.ToString(format: "c0");
}
```

Comment: Steve, what if the groupboxes themselves are in a container as well? You could write this as a recursive and then iterate over the textboxes whenever you find a groupbox? *I plus oned your answer, though.  ;)

Comment: Yes, that's true, we can use recursion, but for the context provided I kept the solution as simple as possible.